# Android fragment does not show anything

Tags: android, webview, android-fragmentactivity

I am sure I am doing this wrong.  This is my first attempt at using a Fragment for anything.  I have a very simple application.  Nothing ever shows up in my tabs.

I am sure it's a stupid mistake somewhere.  Anyone have any ideas?

Here is web.xml:

Next, here is the code from the main activity that should show this webview:
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

```
 SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new WebViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}

public static class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.web, container, false);
        WebView webView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


        return mainView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing.  Apparently if you forget to specify permissions like say for the internet, the WebView doesn't do much.  I wish Android errored out when you make a request you don't have permission for.  I looked at this for 3 hours before posting here.  Should have waited 10 more minutes!